# PHP. Как правильно проверить пустое поле форме или нет?

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Есть форма отправления заявки. По умолчанию все поля обязательные. Как организовать проверку заполнено поле или нет и вывод алертов в случае пустого значения, при это не происходил сброс уже заполненных полей. Сейчас происходит так: если не заполнено хотя бы одно поле, то происходит обновление формы и сброс уже заполненных полей. Помогите пожалуйста дорабатываю чужой код((

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   ....

    var sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> = [ //массив сопоставлений
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #nameWork_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[NAME][0]"},
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #dateStart_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[DATE_ACTIVE_FROM][0]"},
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #dateEnd_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[DATE_ACTIVE_TO][0]"},
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #laborInput_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[18][0]"},
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #workDuration_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[19][0]"},
        {orig: ".bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> #developmentTime_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>", now: "PROPERTY[20][0]"},
    ];

    for (index = 0; index < sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>.length; ++index) {
        $(sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].orig).val($(".form_id_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> input[name='" + sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].now + "']").val());
    }
    <?if(strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), '/bids/') === false ):?>
       if ($('#nameWork_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>').val()) {
        $('#set-view-bid').html('<b>Просмотреть заявку<b>');
    }
    <?endif;?>

    $(" div.btn_submit_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").on('click', function(){
        var formID = $(this).attr('formID');

        $('.files-box_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>').append($('.bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> .files-block').detach());
        for (index = 0; index < sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>.length; ++index) {
            // alert(sopArray[index].orig + ' - ' + sopArray[index].now);
            $('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[name='" + sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].now + "']").val($(sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].orig).val());
        }
        $('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[type='submit']").click();
    });
})
```

В моем случае я думаю нужно делать проверку на пустоту таким образом:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
            if ($("#nameWork_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").val() != '') $('#errIdLOGIN').hide();
            if ($("#dateStart_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").val() != '') $('#errIdPASSWORD').hide();
            if ($("#dateEnd_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").val() != '') $('#errIdCONFIRM_PASSWORD').hide();
            if ($("#laborInput_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").val() != '') $('#errIdEMAIL').hide();
        } else {
            $("#form-button").click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: покажите HTML код

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - это добавить ко всем нужным   "required". В таком случае, после нажатия submit сначала будут проверены эти поля, и если они будут пусты, то браузер их сам подсветит с подсказкой, но перезагрузка страницы не произойдет и заполненные поля не очистятся

Comment: в моем случае не работает((

Answer (score 0):

Если используется JQuery, можно посмотреть в сторону плагинов валидаторов форм, на подобие [этого](http://www.formvalidator.net/).

Если всё-таки хочется самому сделать, то нужно повесить обработчик на форму на событие submit, чтобы перед отправкой проверялись значения полей и если всё ок, то отправлялось, иначе выводился алерт.

Answer (score 0):

required - хорошая штука, но даже сейчас есть динозавры, которые это не поддерживают, или отрубают через консоль забавы ради, если работать по канону, сначала мы должны проверить пустоту форм на клиенте

```
var value = document.getElementById('input').value
```

отлично подойдет для решения данной проблемы (это мы делаем, что бы не грузить наш любимый сервер лишними запросами)

ну и под конец на сервере принимаем параметр, и проверяем еще раз.

```
if(empty($_POST['input'])){
     do something...
}
```